# CSS variables to decrease CSS file

Tags: css

I have

```
.excel { background-image:url(/image/icon/silk/excel.png) !important }
```

Can I use variables in place of *excel*? So that I won't need to make a CSS file for all 1200 icons.

Comment: If these long URLs are really annoying you, you can put the CSS file referencing the images at the `/image/icon/silk/` directory, and use `url(excel.png)` instead. **URLs are resolved relative to the stylesheet's location**.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can use CSS image sprites: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ and define the background position. Or you can get LESS, which relies on Javascript: http://lesscss.org/. LESS does allow you to set variables for colors, class names, etc., but not all browsers support it, which is the downside. However, it's become increasingly popular, so it's worth checking out!

Comment: "Not all browsers support it". LESS is a CSS pre-processor, it's not to be used in a production site. LESS parses a LESS stylesheets in CSS using JavaScript, then applies it. When JS is disabled, the page would be styleless - not a good idea.

Comment: Or just compile the stylesheet with `lessc` before pushing to production

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible.

You can build the css style inline

```
<div style = "background-image:url(<%=imageSrc%>) !important">
</div>
```

Here I used JSP Scriplet. 
imageSrc is a Java variable assuming it contains the image Source.

You can just replace the scriplet with your language syntax.